# Outputting batch/epoch training loss during `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to output my loss with `MonitoredTrainingSession` every epoch or batch.
Ideally I would love to get a flag that the epoch is ended or be able to provide a callback like in keras. I see that I can also do it by manually counting steps, but I want to use the tf functionality, which seems still poorly documented.

From what I could find in their documentation, one can use `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook` to print the tensors every `n` steps.

The problem however is that it prints with frequency different from what I request. When I run following with `every_n_iter=4` I get output every 2nd iteration:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with g.as_default():
    loghook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook([tf.reduce_mean(loss, name='m_loss')],
                                         every_n_iter=4,
                                         formatter=lambda x: "LOSS\t%.4f" % [tt for kk,tt in x.items() if kk.name.startswith('m_loss')][-1]
                                        )
    optimizer = get_optimizer(lr=lr, opt_name = opt_name)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:    
        sess.run(init_op)
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(log_step_count_steps=1, hooks=[loghook]) as sess:
        losslist = []
        while not sess.should_stop():
            print('.')
            loss_ = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={K.learning_phase():1})
            sess.run(training_op)
            losslist.append(np.mean(loss_))
```

I am getting output like:

```
.
INFO:tensorflow:LOSS    2.2416
.
.
INFO:tensorflow:LOSS    2.1547
.
.
INFO:tensorflow:LOSS    2.1186
.
.
```

etc. That is it outputs every 2nd step, not every 4th.

The documentation says:

```
every_n_iter: `int`, print the values of `tensors` once every N local
      steps taken on the current worker.
```

I am running it on one local machine. Why one "local step" equals two loop python iterations? Why two and not five?

Looking at the Python source does not seem helping. Any Google folks aware of what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"local step" is incremented on every call to `sess.run()`. You are calling `sess.run()` twice within your while loop.

Here are some pointers to relevant code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py#L255 - increment _iter_count after every call to `sess.run()`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py#L228 - If `_iter_count` should trigger logging, add the current tensors to be run in the following call to `sess.run()` so that their values can be logged next.